# EC2 - Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems, bundler

I am deploying a rails app to EC2 with using Capistrano, but within the deployment process, I got

```
...
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
    command finished in 344ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
...
```

I am not sure what's the problem, here's the list of installed gems on EC2:

```
bundler (1.3.5)
rake (10.0.4)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.7)
```

**ruby -v**

```
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]
```

Can anyone give me a tip how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some details:

Are you using rvm ?

What is the rails version in your Gemfile ?

Gem version ?

If you are using rvm, check for the gemset being used, remove .bundle and do a fresh **$ bundle** to install the gems.

Post the entire o/p from command **$ gem list** from your project folder.